# Can this query about finding missing keys be improved? (either SQL or LINQ)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I am developing a ASP.NET MVC website and is looking a way to improve this routine. It can be improved either at LINQ level or SQL Server level. I hope at best we can do it within one query call.

Here is the tables involved and some example data:
[image]

We have no constraint that every `Key` has to have each `LanguageId` value, and indeed the business logic does not allow such contraint. However, at application level, we want to warn the admin that a key is missing a/some language values. So I have this class and query:

```
public class LocalizationKeyWithMissingCodes
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> MissingCodes { get; set; }
}
```

This method get the Key list, as well as any missing codes (for example, if we have en + jp + ch language codes, and the key only has values for en + ch, the list will contains jp):

```
    public IEnumerable<LocalizationKeyWithMissingCodes> GetAllKeysWithMissingCodes()
    {
        var languageList = Utils.ResolveDependency<ILanguageRepository>().GetActive();
        var languageIdList = languageList.Select(q => q.Id);
        var languageIdDictionary = languageList.ToDictionary(q => q.Id);

        var keyList = this.GetActive()
            .Select(q => q.Key)
            .Distinct();

        var result = new List<LocalizationKeyWithMissingCodes>();
        foreach (var key in keyList)
        {
            // Get missing codes
            var existingCodes = this.Get(q => q.Active && q.Key == key)
                .Select(q => q.LanguageId);

            // ToList to make sure it is processed at application
            var missingLangId = languageList.Where(q => !existingCodes.Contains(q.Id))
                .ToList();
            result.Add(new LocalizationKeyWithMissingCodes()
            {
                Key = key,
                MissingCodes = missingLangId
                    .Select(q => languageIdDictionary[q.Id].Code),
            });
        }

        result = result.OrderByDescending(q => q.MissingCodes.Count() > 0)
            .ThenBy(q => q.Key)
            .ToList();

        return result;
    }
```

I think my current solution is not good, because it make a query call for each key. Is there a way to improve it, by either making it faster, or pack within one query call?

EDIT: This is the final query of the answer:

```
    public IQueryable<LocalizationKeyWithMissingCodes> GetAllKeysWithMissingCodes()
    {
        var languageList = Utils.ResolveDependency<ILanguageRepository>().GetActive();
        var localizationList = this.GetActive();

        return localizationList
            .GroupBy(q => q.Key, (key, items) => new LocalizationKeyWithMissingCodes()
            {
                Key = key,
                MissingCodes = languageList
                    .GroupJoin(
                        items,
                        lang => lang.Id,
                        loc => loc.LanguageId,
                        (lang, loc) => loc.Any() ? null : lang)
                    .Where(q => q != null)
                    .Select(q => q.Code)
            }).OrderByDescending(q => q.MissingCodes.Count() > 0) // Show the missing keys on the top
            .ThenBy(q => q.Key);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possibility, using LINQ:

```
public IEnumerable<LocalizationKeyWithMissingCodes> GetAllKeysWithMissingCodes(
    List<Language> languages,
    List<Localization> localizations)
{
    return localizations
        .GroupBy(x => x.Key, (key, items) => new LocalizationKeyWithMissingCodes
        {
            Key = key,
            MissingCodes = languages
                .GroupJoin( // check if there is one or more match for each language
                    items,
                    x => x.Id,
                    y => y.LanguageId,
                    (x, ys) => ys.Any() ? null : x)
                .Where(x => x != null) // eliminate all languages with a match
                .Select(x => x.Code) // grab the code
        })
        .Where(x => x.MissingCodes.Any()); // eliminate all complete keys 
}
```

Comment: This is amazing! I could never think of it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the SQL logic to identify the keys that are missing "complete" language assignments:

```
SELECT
    all.[Key],
    all.LanguageId
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        loc.[Key],
        lang.LanguageId
    FROM
        Language lang
    FULL OUTER JOIN
        Localization loc
        ON (1 = 1)
    WHERE
        lang.Active = 1
    ) all
LEFT JOIN
    Localization loc
    ON (loc.[Key] = all.[Key])
    AND (loc.LanguageId = all.LanguageId)
WHERE
    loc.[Key] IS NULL;
```

To see all keys (instead of filtering):

```
SELECT
    all.[Key],
    all.LanguageId,
    CASE WHEN loc.[Key] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Flagged
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        loc.[Key],
        lang.LanguageId
    FROM
        Language lang
    FULL OUTER JOIN
        Localization loc
        ON (1 = 1)
    WHERE
        lang.Active = 1
    ) all
LEFT JOIN
    Localization loc
    ON (loc.[Key] = all.[Key])
    AND (loc.LanguageId = all.LanguageId);
```

Comment: This is indeed true for getting the keys (there was a typo, it is `lang.Id`), but I don't know why I get duplicate records on the same `Key` and `LanguageId` (I think the problem with the Active = 0 records), althought I added your condition to `WHERE lang.Active = 1 AND loc.Active = 1`.

Comment: Sure, I don't know the ins-and-outs of your table logic, but overall the above should work. Does it work with your edits?

Comment: Yes, remove the duplicate, it seems to work, I will check and try to convert it to LINQ query and tell you the result. Also, my requirement is to return every keys, whether or not they have missing values.

Comment: See my edit - I added a different version per your comment.

Comment: I still get tons of duplicate records and have no idea how to eliminate them. Basically, I have the `Active` field in every table, to mark them as Deleted (0) or is real business record (1). I tried using the LINQ `Except` statement and it seems working well. I do not know its SQL equivalent though.

Comment: Without seeing the data, it is really hard for me to figure out your duplicate record issue. My guess is that there are duplicate data in the tables - but that I would not know.

Answer (score 1):

your code seems to be doing a lot of database query and materialization..

in terms of LINQ, the single query would look like this..

we take the cartesian product of language and localization tables to get all combinations of (key, code) and then subtract the (key, code) tuples that exist in the relationship. this gives us the (key, code) combination that don't exist.

```
var result = context.Languages.Join(context.Localizations, lang => true, 
loc => true, (lang, loc) => new { Key = loc.Key, Code = lang.Code })
.Except(context.Languages.Join(context.Localizations, lang => lang.Id, 
loc => loc.LanguageId, (lang, loc) => new { Key = loc.Key, Code = lang.Code }))
.GroupBy(r => r.Key).Select(r => new LocalizationKeyWithMissingCodes 
{ 
 Key = r.Key, 
 MissingCodes = r.Select(kc => kc.Code).ToList()
})
.ToList()
.OrderByDescending(lkmc => lkmc.MissingCodes.Count())
.ThenBy(lkmc => lkmc.Key).ToList();
```

p.s. i typed this LINQ query on the go, so let me know if it has syntax issues..
the gist of the query is that we take a cartesian product and subtract matching rows.

Comment: This is the first time I have ever seen LINQ `Include`. What is it? I could not pass it, because `l => l.Localization` does not exist, there is only `l.Localizations`, and so on the next Select statement, I could not select the `Key`, as `l.Localizations` is a collection.

Comment: Should I just use a second join as parameter for the `Except`?

Comment: yes.. i updated the answer to just join on the language id for the 2nd resultset..

Comment: @DatVM Include is basic LINQ - if you miss that, better go and read the documentation for other "hidden" features. It instructs the mapper to preload the related objects. Select invoices INCLUDE invoice lines means that reading the lines will not cause additional SQL statements to be issued. This is why it is fundamental - without it you get a ton of small SQL when traversing navigation properties. And this is so basic and central to performance that anyone caught not knowing about it really should consider how much he really ever learned about LINQ.

Comment: @TomTom Thank you very much, TIL!

Comment: @TomTom, Just for the record, `Include` is a basic feature of EntityFramework (or LINQ to Entities), not LINQ to Objects.

Comment: Yes, because it makes no sense on LINQtoObjects - as no slow access happens. LINQ2Objects has no on demand mechanism at all ;)

Comment: @TomTom, Absolutely, but the question doesn't mention EntityFramework, and for someone not familiar with EntityFramework, I wouldn't consider `Include` to be "basic LINQ".